# MDBootstrap install command - which one is correct?

Tags: angular-material, material-design, mdbootstrap

I want to install MDBootstrap(materil design for bootstrap) but I have found two commands.

```
=> npm install mdbootstrap
or
=> npm install angular-bootstrap-md
```

I am not sure what is the difference between above two commands(packages).
Are they same or different? If different then what is the difference between them?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `mdbootstrap` adds the css/js files of the mdboostrap library.


`angular-bootstrap-md`, is a package containing ready-to-use  components for Angular, these components have of the course the look&feel of mdbootstrap css